Is using trim helpful on the final when landing?
I remember my old instructor used trim during traffic pattern. I believe it is pretty common on the downwind but he also trimmed on the final before and during the round out and flare especially short field landing. It felt like doing slow flight descending on the final and the landing and touchdown were really smooth. (smoothest ever actually)
Nevertheless he did not mention the use of trim on the round out and flare phase, and other instructors either. today I imitate that instructor and use trim enough to maintain Vy pitch during flaring but is that a proper technique??

You trim to maintain any pitch condition you expect to continue for more than, say, 15 or 30 seconds. So, for each speed change, you trim hands off to hold that attitude/speed. On short final you should be trimmed for the appropriate approach speed so that no control force is required. In the landing phase, you forget about trim and just work the pitch to control the landing.
Generally it's a bad practice to roll in more nose up trim to reduce the control forces in the flare. The reason is that if you go-around, you will find yourself at high power, needing to accelerate to best rate of climb, and trimmed for a speed way below that. So the nose comes up, and you have to push hard to maintain the correct speed, frantically retrimming to the proper climb speed. If a distraction happens while this is going on that lets you relax your push, you could slow down and find yourself about to stall.
The urge to do it can be intense in some airplanes: I recall that the Piper Seminole had very high pitch forces (almost needing two hands) in the flare and it was common to roll in an extra shot of nose up trim to reduce the force at the start of the flare.
Same problem though, and potentially even more dangerous in a light piston twin, is if you need to do a go around from the flare after retrimming to help reduce pitch forces, (say a cow walks onto the runway) and an engine quits at that moment, you will really have your hands full. You need to accelerate to blue line, go though the single engine drill, and retrim to control the tendency to pitch up hard.

Probably not relevant for the OP, but there are some aircraft (e.g. B737) where the autopilot trims more nose up than needed (at 1500ft above aerodrome elevation) to reduce required control forces during an autoland.

Yeah that was a workaround to avoid having to upgrade to a more powerful pitch servo. The servo is made to push to hold the slope, which gives it much more range to pull when the time comes.

Is the trim helpful on the final when landing?
Absolutely.  Trimming will lock in a safe approach speed.
No more "high, low, fast, or slow".  Just "high or low".

but remember, the aircraft must remain on the glide path to hold speed.

Once rounding starts, the aircraft is constantly slowing down, requiring more and more increase in angle of attack to remain flying.
This is why they tell you to raise the nose or "flare" as the aircraft settles down to the runway.
One should not be reaching for a trim wheel at this point, when bringing the yoke or stick smoothly back is all that is needed as airspeed bleeds off.
Your instructor may have been showing you that in an emergency trim can be used to control pitch, but finer control can be had by hand feel while eyes are out the window or on the airspeed indicator.
